# When we laugh or run for sport which autonomic system works?

Tags: physiology, autonomic-nervous-system

When we **laugh** or **run for sport** which *autonomic system* takes place in this time?

While I am not sure what happens in heart while laughing (tachycardia or bradycardia), but for sport running I'm sure that the heart has tachycardia. Does it mean that the sympathetic system works there (or there isn't relation between them)? If it does, then I really don't understand why being anger cause damage to the cardiovascular while sport running said to be healthy for the cardiovascular system, here are both activate the sympathetic system. Isn't it?

Comment: For laughing, our parasympathetic system works: "Breathing is the only function of the autonomic nervous system that can be consciously regulated or changed. It encourages deep diaphragmatic breathing, which stimulates the parasympathetic nervous system. This is the cooling branch of the autonomic nervous system and is the opposite of the sympathetic stress arousal system. This helps in relaxing the aroused state of a person and provides a sense of calmness." (See here: https://www.laughteronlineuniversity.com/laughter-good-nervous-system/)